# How would you interface a 24 volt rotary encoder to GPIO?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio

This Siko IG07 incremental rotary encoder spits out 24 volts.
[Here are the specs](https://www.siko-global.com/de-de/produkte/rotoline-drehgeber/inkrementale-drehgeber/ig07)

As we know, the Raspberry Pi and Arduino are expecting 3.3 and 5 volts respectively.

This [RPi level shifter Hat](https://www.tindie.com/products/chris_wag/rpi-level-shifter-hat/) looks perfect from 3.3 to 5 volts and the form factor is well thought out.

So I ask you kind souls to please help me find a component.
A transistor array or chip.

Comment: You probably can get away with a simple voltage divider.

Comment: The manual shows there are a number of different models with different output voltages, with suffixes -PP, --LD etc  Do you know the exact model you have?   See the output circuits from page 31 of the [documentation](https://www.siko-global.com/adbimage/28187/asset_original/montageanleitung-ig07.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special level converter. Just use a potential divider to reduce the voltage.

With a 24V input, a divider using 13kΩ and 2kΩ resistors will give you a 3.2V output, which will work fine here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyUt6Dm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will work just fine as long as the rotary encoder's ground connection is tied to your RPi's ground connection.

If the voltage from the rotary encoder might exceed 24V, you could also add a zener diode to clamp the GPIO voltage to 3.3V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ESIOm.png)</sup>

This is probably not necessary in this case.

Comment: Might want to mirror those schematics. It's unconventional for inputs to be on the right and outputs to be on the left.

Answer (score 0):

In the event the signal is noisy, an optocoupler could provide protection for your RPi.
[image: Optocoupler-isolator]
https://www.tindie.com/products/icstation/4bit-24v-to-5v-optocoupler-isolator8042/?pt=ac_prod_search

This one listed appears to work at 20kHz, so it would provide perfect resolution up to 20kHz/1024 ~ 20 RPM, then you would start to see skipping in the output, but without doubt of direction within the RPM rating on the encoder you chose.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a rail clamp since that will preserve the edge better than a voltage divider would and has the advantage of being able to protect against overvoltages that could otherwise still exceed GPIO due to the divider ratio being insufficient.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4udX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that D1 only clamp while Vlogic has power so if the encoder runs while Vlogic is unpowered there is no clamping. This unpowered scenario is the only reason the zener diode D2 is there.

I suppose you could argue that you only need D2, but I believe that D1 is more precise and faster (if you select the correct diode such as a fast diode or a Schottky). It definitely heats up D1 less than D2...but not that it matters with R1 there.